# Virtual sound card on a VPS

Tags: text-to-speech, alsa, soundcard

I am working on an api for conversion from text to speech in native languages .I am trying to implement the same on a VPS server. As a vps server seldom have any sounds cards and I need to have a virtual sound card for task. On some research i figured out that this could be achieved  by using ALSA .

The question here I want to ask is that if I try to compile kernel module on my VPS ( ubuntu  12.10 32bit )  and install that module in my kernel would node become unstable and crash ? I have not tried compiling as this could cause a lot of issues (loss of data )

Any help would be appreciated .

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "virtual sound card"? Should that card ignore the playback data, or write it to a file, or allow to capture it? Must it run in real time?